# ListView Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, android-adapter

I wanted to create a `ListView` adapter to display multiple data, such as `Username`, `Comment`, `Date` and `Rating` together in one row. It's like displaying comments in the forums. I have 4 arrays and each of the array stores one of these value (`Username`, `Comment`, `Date` and `Rating`). I tried using the below code to create a custom adapter for this. But I don't really know the correct way to implement this. I tried running this and it only displayed out `Username` and `Date`. I'm not sure whether this code is the correct way to implement or not.

```
Float f = Float.parseFloat(commentRating[position]);
holder.cmtRating.setRating(f);
```

**Content.java**:

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.commentlist);
adapter=new CommentAdapter(ContentScreen.this);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

public class CommentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public CommentAdapter(Activity a) {
        activity = a;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return commentText.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        public TextView cmtUser;
        public TextView cmtText;
        public RatingBar cmtRating;
        public TextView cmtTime;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.cmtUser = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.commentby);
            holder.cmtText = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            holder.cmtRating = (RatingBar) vi.findViewById(R.id.commentrating);
            holder.cmtTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.commentcreatedby);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        holder.cmtUser.setText(commentBy[position]);
        holder.cmtText.setText(commentText[position]);
        Float f = Float.parseFloat(commentRating[position]);
        holder.cmtRating.setRating(f);
        holder.cmtTime.setText(commentCreatedTime[position]);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Any answers and comments are appreciated.

**EDIT**

comment.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/commentcreatedby"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/commentby"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/commentcreatedby"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/commentby"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/commentrating"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
```

content.xml

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/top_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/header" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content_desc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_header"
    android:padding="10dip"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/content_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/content_desc"
    android:padding="10dip" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/commentlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/content_price" >

</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/content_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/content_subscribe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/commentlist"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:paddingRight="20dip"
    android:text="Subscribe" />
```

**UPDATE**

The rating is working as well. But it stacked together with the date. As for the comment, I still cant get it working.

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**
Apparently it's my comment.xml arrangement got some sort of issue. Once I re-arrange it, the comment appear and everything works fine. Thank you for everyone's time.

Comment: How is your xml? Do you have everything showing there?

Comment: Your Adapter looks fine, post `comment.xml` so we can see if the problem is in the layout.  Does `commentText[position]` return a non-empty String?

Comment: That can't be all of your xml

Comment: Have you put dummy data in your xml to see if it shows in the graphical view?

Comment: @codeMagic Sorry. That wasn't my entire xml. I included another xml into the question as well. Yes. I did tried input some dummy data in my xml. Everything's okay

Comment: @Sam I tried check it with Log.i(TAG, "cmtText:" +commentText[position]); It returns the correct value. But it just wont't appear in the listview

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 reasons that this may happen:

1. You last two arrays are not filled with data/or filled with empty data and that the reason they are not presented.
   (less likely because you would receive a null pointer exception when you try to access a null location in the array)
2. You row layout doesn't show the last two data parameters.
   (I will be on this reason, please show you row layout XML so that we could check it)

Make a check and print to the log all the data from 4 the arrays for every row before you set the data in the `getView` method.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I confirmed that I have data inside the last two array. But I just don't know why it only shows the username and Date. I have included the comment.xml in the question. I'll  check at the getview method as well now